# How to customize the admin toolbar in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, theming

I'm trying to customize the administration toolbar in Drupal 7 but I don't know how to do it.
I'd like to add custom links (e.g node/add/[content-type]) and links that are only available for specific users.

[Edit] Finally, I used [admin_menu module](http://drupal.org/project/admin_menu) and I added a menu item with a custom module using [hook_admin_menu_output_alter](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--admin_menu--admin_menu.api.php/function/hook_admin_menu_output_alter/7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the shortcut module that's in core, that's what it's for. The Toolbar wasn't designed to add custom links because the shortcut bar was (from what I understand). Ironically the [Drupal 6 backport module](http://drupal.org/project/toolbar) of the module does have this feature.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Then, is it possible to have a fully custom admin menu? My guess is to use a module, but which module? And will I be able to fully tweak the admin navigation ? 
Also, I thought about disabling the toolbar, and creating a new menu from scratch. Is this a viable solution ?

Comment: As I mention on my answer with the shortcut module that comes with core, you can add a custom set of links in a top toolbar for your clients. hth

Comment: Yes, I understand that I can add custom links, but the problem is that I can't set a set of shortcuts for each roles. There's a [module](http://drupal.org/sandbox/babbar.ankit/1150940) available in the sandbox that can do the trick  , but it's still a sandbox project and I don't think it's suitable for a production site

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Quickbar](http://drupal.org/project/quickbar) module.This is a simple administration toolbar. It allows you to take any menu and assign it to a role. This menu will be displayed at the top of your page as an administration toolbar.

You could also look at the [Manager](http://drupal.org/project/manager) module. It includes the Manager's Bar. An admin-bar designed for users that aren't familiar with Drupal. It is like the default "Navigation" menu, when we cut off everything that doesn't matter to this users, and it looks like some known admin-bar-modules, like Admin Menu, but a lot more simple.

Comment: Thanks for the links, but the two modules are quite buggy and i can't even install them (errors on install). And, I can't afford to have buggy modules on a site for a client.